# Adding new custom column to Forecast Type in Forecasts

Tags: formula, custom-field, forecast, column, customizable-forecasts

I haven't worked with forecasts before, but I'm required to add a new column to appear in one of our Quota tracking reports. The main fields of the report are Forecast Category and Quota amount, and the requirement is to have a new column calculated from those values. The logic is:

1. If the Forecast Category is  Pipeline, the value on the new column should be Quota amount*0.1
2. If the Forecast Category is  Best Case, the value on the new column should be Quota amount*0.25
3. If the Forecast Category is  Commit, the value on the new column should be Quota amount*0.5
4. If the Forecast Category is  Closed, the value on the new column should be Quota amount*0.8

I've encounter two issues so far, the first issue is with the syntax of the Custom Column formulas,  they are quite different form a regular SF formula field. I've been using approaches like this with no results:

```
IF(ForecastCategoryName = "Pipeline"  , ForecastAmount*0.1, IF(ForecastCategoryName = "Best Case"  , ForecastAmount*0.25, 0))
```

And so far I always got this error: [image]

The other issue is the maximum length of the formula, It won't be possible for me to cover the 4 cases with the max length of this formula editor. I've thought of having two new columns instead, one for the first two cases, and the other one for the remaining two.

I appreciate any guidance you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

maybe consider to use directly the values, Here you can find the appropriate API column Names: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_forecastingcolumndefinition.htm

```
ForecastAmount0+ForecastAmount1*0.9+ForecastAmount2*0.7+ForecastAmount3*0.2
```

[image]